# InvalidArgument=Value of '5' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'

Tags: c#, combobox, selectedindex

I read saved data from tbl in a list, and i want to edit the object, so when i start the program, combobox first to show saved value for that object, and others also to be in the combobox. Please help !

```
if (lstP.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lstP.Count; i++)
    {
        if (Stav.IDP == lstP[i].SP)
        {
            Prim.SelectedIndex = lstP[i].SP;
            //ERROR
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `Prim.Items.Count`?

Comment: It is probably saying that you do not have anything on index 5 in combobox. Is it contains only 5 elements, which makes only available 4 value maximum? Also the code can be changed to `Prim.SelectedIndex = Stav.IDP` in if statement.

Comment: It`s the same that lstP[i].Sp.

Comment: I forgot to say that i have already Prim.SelectedIndex event, can the event cause some problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SelectedIndex requires a number to be passed. What you need is to assign an `i` to it:

```
if (lstP.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lstP.Count; i++)
    {
        if (Stav.IDP == lstP[i].SP)
        {
            Prim.SelectedIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, yes thank you, i didn`t even think about that. It helped and works, thanks a lot.